# How to access to variables inside models from any controller Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Hi everybody I want to store column names from my database using models because Im building an web application and names from the columns are difficult for humans.

I want to write and call that name in every eloquent query. The database already exists. In my opinion models are the best option but I don't know how to achieve this.

```
protected $table = 'products';
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to access all column names of a table.This code will return all columns of a table.

$column_names = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('products');